# Lubuntu is not able to read file names with cyrillic characters

Tags: lubuntu, encoding, filename, cyrillic

I would be grateful for helping in resolving the following issue. Cyrillic characters in file names are rendered with octal escape sequence codes in Konsole. For example, the file name

Тест.txt

is rendered as

''$'\320\242\320\265\321\201\321\202''.txt'

Dolphin and other GUI programs do not see those files at all. Such names were rendered normally as recently as yesterday, the trouble started all of a sudden this morning for no obvious reason (at least no one played with language settings, encodings or any thing like that).

I use fresh installation of Lubuntu 20.04 x64.

Output of locale:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory 

LANG=en_US.UTF-8

LANGUAGE=

LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"

LC_NUMERIC=ba_RU.UTF-8

LC_TIME=ba_RU.UTF-8

LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"

LC_MONETARY=ba_RU.UTF-8

LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"

LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8

LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8

LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8

LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8

LC_MEASUREMENT=ba_RU.UTF-8

LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8

LC_ALL=
```

Output of file ~/Тест.txt:

```
/home/sergey/Тест.txt: empty
```

Comment: What is the output of `locale`? What does `file Тест.txt`return?

Comment: @Fiximan It is as follows:

locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

LANG=en_US.UTF-8

LANGUAGE=

LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"

LC_NUMERIC=ba_RU.UTF-8

LC_TIME=ba_RU.UTF-8

LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"

LC_MONETARY=ba_RU.UTF-8

LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"

LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8

LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8

LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8

LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8

LC_MEASUREMENT=ba_RU.UTF-8

LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8

LC_ALL=

sergey@sn-5-hrl:~$ file ~/Тест.txt

/home/sergey/Тест.txt: empty

Comment: Sorry for formatting. I can't convert it to normal multi-line output for whatever reason.

Comment: Please add additional information to your question (formatting control is far greater in questions & answers).

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. Go to «Preferences / LXQt settings / Locale» and verify the input fields. In my case all of them except for the upmost one some how changed to «Russia - (ba_RU)». Setting them to  «Россия - русский (ru_RU)» followed by rebooting has had the desired effect.